# Insert text in cells when above cell meets condition ( if it has any number )

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, ms-office

I have sheet filled with customers orders. The fith(E5) column has an unique identifier when a product is open box ( a number )

My plan is to make a rule with conditional formating ( VBA would be better if possible ), that write the word research on column(cell) O5 if the fith column(cell) has any number( and so on)
I'm trying to set up a loop that does this for all the cells on column E( after E5 ) and O ( after O5 ) and no luck so far.

[image]

(A small example of what I want to do, data start after row 5)

I'm guessing VBA is the way to go, but the VBA code I've found so far seems to use specific cells and wouldn't go through each column.

Thank you for your time and help.

I tried conditional formating and is not working correctly ( or the way that I want it to work )

Comment: hard to understand for me: why not adding some shots and, even better, examples of your attempts (be them VBA code or conditional formatting)

Comment: Sorry I wrote everything on my phone and some of the formatting broke.

Comment: I still don't get it all: you said you need to insert a word (I guess you mean to write a word into a cell) and tried conditional formatting which however wouldn't write anything into cells

Comment: A simple formula in Column O would work best: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E2)),"Research","")`

Comment: Or `IF(ISNUMBER(E5), "Research", "")` VBA seems WAY overpowered for this. Also, since no cells are getting formatted, "Conditional formatting" isn't the right path.

Comment: Is there a way to make the formula loop ? Make it go from E5 to E6 to E7 and then do the same with O5 O6 O7 and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make the loop work using VBA.

Code :

```vb
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long 

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To lastRow
   If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "E").Value) Then
      Cells(i, "O").Value ="Research"
   End If
Next i
```